# "So" and "So that"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, adverbs

Suppose these sentences I made with "so"

> The main idea is to place it somewhere **so** everyone can use it
>
> Please bend **so** I can pass
>
> It is built in a way **so** you can bend it and it doesn't break

Are they correct ways to use "so"?

Should or can I use "so that" instead of them?

Are "so" and "so that" interchangeable? Can I reduce "so that" always to "so"?

If "so" is informal? which phrase can I use instead of it in the sentences above?

Comment: A good thread is here: [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/are-so-and-so-that-interchangeable)

Comment: It really doesn't matter technically; however, so that sounds unnecessarily formal. Also, so and that are both conjunctions, so *so that* s like a double conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these correct ways to use 'so'?

Yes you have used 'so' correctly

> Should or Can I use 'so that' instead of 'so'?

These examples can use 'so' or 'so that' interchangeably, I cannot think of a case in which they are not interchangeable.

> Is 'so' is informal

So is not generally considered informal unless:

It occurs at the beginning of a sentance. E.g. 'So what does this mean' can become more formal by omitting the 'so'   I.e 'What does this mean.'

> What can be used in place of 'so' for formality?

'So that' is considered more formal than 'so'

Depending on the context 'so' can be replaced by other words such as:

'We should do X so Y' can be changed to 'We should do X because Y'

Comment: "so" and "so that" are not always interchangeable, when "so" means "therefore", like *I finished my dish, so I am going to watch TV*. Moreover, your last example is incorrect, because "so" in that sentence doesn't mean "because" and is used incorrectly check this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/are-so-and-so-that-interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

**So** is used for the effect or result and **so that** to tell for what purpose something is done.