# Usage of "so that” vs. “so"

Tags: so

Which version is better?

> Let me know when you are going to send it **so** I can make the payment.

or:

> Let me know when you are going to send it **so that** I can make the payment.

I think ***so*** is better because the payment is the effect: you send the book, and the effect is that I must pay.

Comment: This is one of those cases where "that" is optional. See also [“So” and “So that”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/96952/271), [“So if …” vs “so that if …”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/177023/271), [Are “so” and “so that” both acceptable here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/127881/271) etc, not to mention other constructs without "so"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It expresses the *purpose* of the requested future action, so the expression '*so that*' is more appropriate (despite *colloquially*, '**that**' may be omitted):

> Let me know when you are going to send it **so (that)** I can make the
>   payment.

An example where it's an *effect*:

> You've sent it to me, **so** I can make the payment now.

https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-9.html

Answer (score 0):

The first option is more informal than the second option, but both are acceptable and grammatically correct - the 'that' is optional.